# Full stop at end of tag name - recognised by the system in some places and not others

Tags: bug, tags

A tag with a full stop at the end of its name, like `example-tag.`, is recognised as the same tag as `example-tag` in some parts of the system but not in others. For example:

- putting a full stop into the end of a tag while editing a question seems to be impossible (it just redirects back to the tag without the full stop);
- an attempt to mod-merge a tag without a full stop into the same tag with a full stop yielded a "can't merge a tag into itself" error;

but:

- clicking on the tag name with a full stop doesn't redirect to the tag without the full stop.

I came across this while trying to create a tag for [*The Rise and Fall of D.O.D.O.*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32075825-the-rise-and-fall-of-d-o-d-o) at the SFF Stack Exchange. The current tag looks like [the-rise-and-fall-of-d.o.d.o](/questions/tagged/the-rise-and-fall-of-d.o.d.o), and it seems to be impossible to rename this tag to have the full stop at the end, but clicking on [the tag name with the full stop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-rise-and-fall-of-d.o.d.o.) gives a list of 0 questions rather than redirecting to [the list without the full stop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-rise-and-fall-of-d.o.d.o).